# Windows Serial Communication, Handle Parity bit

Tags: c++, c, windows, serial-port, parity

I am coding with serial communication in windows.
In this communication, in order for program to recognize a start of message, i have to use parity bit.

It means that if the byte received with setting parity bit is a start point of a message.

For example, If receiving bytes like below from a serial port
(`[byte]` means a byte received, and `[byte]p` means a byte with setting a parity bit)

> Serial port <-[byte]<-  [byte]<-  [byte]<-  [byte]<-  [byte]p<-  [byte] : sequence bytes received

I have to parse above the message after discarding 4 bytes before a byte with setting parity bit.

In the case of Linux, a Setting parity bit is represented as `0XFF 0x00` so if i receive 1 byte 0xEE with parity.
It is denoted as `0xFF 0x00 0xEE`, so that I can picked the start point.

But in windows, parity bit seems to be represented as event `EV_ERR` by `WaitCommEvent()`
And read data separately by `ReadFile()`.

I think it is difficult to find out where parity error happen to distinguish a start point of message.

Is there any way to solve this problem, actually since i am new at windows programming, i think there must exist other way, right ?

Comment: Protocols like this are invented by companies that also have the hardware to sell you.  Knowing full well that you don't stand a chance to implement it yourself.  Buy the product.

Comment: *"[byte]p means a byte with setting a parity bit"* -- You seem to be trying to describe a 9-bit character.  The parity bit would be the high-order bit.  So the correct representation should be p<byte>.  For possible solutions see http://superuser.com/questions/411386/seeking-9-bit-serial-port-card-for-windows-pc/411438#411438

Comment: If you can take over the parity bit in software, then every 8-bit UART with parity is secretly a 9-bit UART without parity, just need to twiddle the bits to put everything in the correctly bit order again.  Its a pity M$ hasn't updated their Serial Port Driver in years...You might fare better with Linux... and 9-bits is the holy grail for easy framing of control and data...

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.errorreceived?view=netframework-4.8) seems clear on how parity errors are handled (or not): "Because the operating system determines whether to raise this event or not, not all parity errors may be reported"